# CUDA toolkit -- Nvidia drivers -- login loop -- no glx extension

Tags: nvidia, xorg

Please, somebody end this nightmare.

Every couple of weeks for the past several months I've tried to enable GPU support on my machine (which I've done before in the past somehow when I was on an older OS) but cannot get it working.

I've followed the [CUDA installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) to a tee.

I've tried the `runfile [local]`, `deb [local]`, and `deb [network]` installations from the [CUDA toolkit download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604).

I've tried installing Nvidia drivers using the following methods:

- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`
- from a `.run` file downloaded from the [Nvidia drivers page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
- selecting the 390 and 396 drivers from `Software & Updates -> Additional drivers` [image]

The first thing I tried today was installing with `runfile [local]` -- this resulted in a login loop. I found a suggestion [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/987718/cuda-setup-and-installation/infinite-login-loop-after-attempted-runfile-installation-of-cuda-8-0-toolkit-on-ubuntu-14-04/) stating to say `no` to installing the OpenGL libraries. I tried installing again without the OpenGL libraries, but then I my screen resolution was all messed up (`couldn't find configs for CRTC` or something like that). After searching around some more, it seemed like saying `no` to allowing Nvidia to create a xconfig file was the solutions -- doing so prevented the resolution issue, but then, obviously, the drivers were not configured to use the Nvidia card. Running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and rebooting caused a login loop again.

I then switched to trying all the other methods in various combinations, all of which resulted in a login loop.

Taking a look at `.xsession-errors` showed that glx extension was missing for the display. I tried searching for a solution -- the only think I found was a [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254377/xlib-extension-glx-missing-with-an-nvidia-card-and-on-board-graphics?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to install OpenGL using `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` and adding a couple lines to the `Files` section of my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia-VERSION/xorg"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection
```

This didn't resolve the glx issue though.

Here's my system info:

```
-> lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev ff)

-> uname -r
4.4.0-121-generic

-> uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Here's an example of my `xorg.conf` after running `nvidia-xconfig` during one of the attempts:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 387.26  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-08)  Thu Nov  2 21:38:15 PDT 2017


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Here's a link to my [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](https://pastebin.com/DmVvaK2b):

I know this question will probably be received with "here we go again" and links to a bunch of other posts where the same question is asked...believe me, I've seen them. But I feel like I've looked at every one of them and have had no success. I've probably put in something close to 60 hours trying to enable GPU support -- 6 just today -- and I've never experienced a more soul crushing and frustrating problem. Please help!

Comment: On a standard Ubuntu 16.04, today's latest kernel is 4.4.0-119, not ...121, use Software and Updates/Alternative Drivers to select the Nvidia driver which says "tested". and install that.  Get the login working if necessary (it should just work, but ...) and then tackle CUDA, which should be a trivial download the Intel deb file, install it, and then install the cuda package.  Your biggest task at this point is cleaning up all the non-standard parts that you have added, to get back to a configuration which works.